# Unable to generate digital signature for google static street view API

Tags: google-api, digital-signature, signature, google-street-view, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to use the google static street view API to get an image of a property. The docs for the API state that I need to use a "digital signature": https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview

I am trying to generate a signature, but the guide google provides doesn't seem to make much sense. These are the docs I am reading in regards to generating a signature: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/digital-signature#get-secret

But when I navigate to this page it doesn't seem to show the things mentioned in the docs that allow you to generate secrets.

[image: The page you end up on]

Comment: 1) Secret is optional 2) If I follow the docs you linked, I get to the secret generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Street View Static API or Maps Static API, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/digital-signature#get-secret:%7E:text=We%20strongly%20recommend%20that%20you%20use%20both%20an%20API%20key%20and%20digital%20signature%2C%20regardless%20of%20your%20usage.) specifically says:

> *"We strongly recommend that you use both an API key and digital signature, regardless of your usage."*

Regarding your question, you seem to be on the **Metrics** page instead of the **Credentials** page.
[image: Credentials]

Now on how to generate a digital signature, let me just quote the guide from the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/digital-signature#limit-unsigned-requests) and add some additional details to help you.

> 1. Go to the [Google Maps Platform Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/google/maps-apis/credentials) in the Cloud Console.(You should be on the one I circled on the above image)
> 2. Click the project drop-down and select the same project you used when you created the API key for the Street View Static API.
> 3. Select the APIs drop-down and select **Street View Static API**.
>    [image]
> 4. Scroll down to the **Secret Generator card**. The **Current secret** field contains your current URL signing secret.(If there's no current one, **Generate Secret** button will be the only one you'll see).
> 5. The page also features the **Sign a URL now** widget that allows you to automatically sign a Street View Static API request using your current signing secret. Scroll down to the **Sign a URL now** card to access it.

> To get a new URL signing secret, select **Generate/Regenerate Secret**. If there's an existing one, the previous secret will expire 24 hours after you've generated a new secret. After the 24 hours have passed, requests containing the old secret no longer work.

Since your question is only about **generating digital signature**, you'll have to read the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/digital-signature#construct-unsigned-request) for more details and for the next steps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah yes this seems to be correct. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't figure this out, but turns out you don't actually need to use a signature to access the API.